# How to add data to a tkinter canvas item?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, lambda, tags

I managed to create an infrared picture using a canvas filled with little rectangle items in a 32 x 24 array. Each rectangle has a color to visually create a heat map. The colors give some impression of warm and cold spots.

Now I want to see the exact temperature of the pixel I am hovering over with the mouse. Binding mouse events is not that hard. However, the mouse event only gives me (x,y) screen coordinates.

With a normal TkInter widget w, I can attach custom data like this:

```
w.temperature = 20.3
```

However, with a TkInter Canvas item, such as obtained with `canvas.create_rectangle`, this is not possible, as the item is just an id, an integer. I can add so-called 'tags' to such items, but this does not seem to be useful in the event callback.

Using the (x,y) coordinates to lookup the temperatures is hard, partly because first I have to map (x,y) to the pixel blocks, each of which is 20 x 20 pixels.

Is there really no pythonic way to attach some custom data to each Canvas Item, and retrieve that in the event callback?

Or, now that I am writing this question, is there perhaps some funky syntax to bind the callback to each canvas rectangle item with an extra argument? With javascript react jsx I have seen such things, which was not simple but in a way still elegant, something along the lines of:

```
canvas.create_rectangle......bind(lambda event: mycallback(event, 20.3))
```

I have very little experience with lambda kind of stuff in Python, and am thinking of it just right now, so I have not yet tried it.

---

update:

The lambda idea is nice, but does not work for me, as the `bind` is called on the Canvas, not on the rectangle items.

There seems no other way than to process the x,y and get the pixel temperature from the original input data :-(

However, getting the pixel nr from the pixel coordinates is simple:

```
x = int(event.x / blocksize)
```

and storing the temperatures in a 2-dimensional dictionary is also simple, e.g.:

```
dict_t[x, y] = 20.3
```

Problem solved, no stupid tag needed

Comment: canvas.create.text

Comment: @toyotaSupra thanks, but not sure what you mean. I can add data to the canvas widget, but not to the items created on a canvas

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store the temperature values.

Comment: @acw1668 you are right, there is no other option, see my update to the question

Comment: Or use the *tag* to store the temperature.

Comment: @acw1668 the tag was my first thought, but I could not get the tag value in the event callback. Your idea of the dict was my last option, but turned out to be pretty easy to do, and pretty straightforward. It already works in my app

Comment: You can use `canvas.gettags("current")` to get the tags of the item under the mouse cursor inside the event callback.